# Is it possible to send 2 different textbox values but the same textbox names?

Tags: jsp

Let's say.. I have two textbox:

```
<td>
<input type="text" name="ArmNumber" size="2"/>
<input type="text" name="ArmNumber" size="2"/>
</td>
```

And I write "Hello" on the first textbox.
And I write "World" on the second textbox.

Will it display 2 word ? or only the first input field which is the "Hello" word.

Comment: Try `String values[] = request.getParameterValues("ArmNumber"); `

Answer (score 1):

```
String values[] = request.getParameterValues("num"); 
        // will retrieve all field values entered by user using "getParameterValues()"
        // and store in STRING ARRAY

        out.println("<h3> The Values are </br>");

        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        {
            out.println("<br>" +values[i]); // print all field values entered by user in form
        }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Can I print out "World" only ? Instead of "Hello World". Meaning I print out the second textbox input only

Comment: Not yet. Sorry . Can you help me on my previous post ? I've been stuck on that error for days... And Idk what is wrong.. It is related to this post